# Create new vector based on conditions from another vector

Tags: r

I have a vector `v1 = c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)`. How can I create a vector of equal length BUT with values -1 if 0 or 3 and 1 if 1 or 5.

So with `v1 = c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)`, I am expecting a new vector:

`v2 = c(-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1)`

Comment: In first v1 you have more 1s? typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
v2 <- c(-1,1)[1 + (v1 %in% c(1,5))]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > v2
> [1] -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
> ```

What this does:

- `v1 %in% c(1,5)` creates a logical vector
- by adding `1` you create an integer vector of `1`'s and `2`'s.
- you can use that as an index vector on `c(-1,1)` which will create the required result

---

For when `v1` contains other numbers than `0`, `1`, `3` or `5` you should be more explicit:

```
v2 <- c(-1,1)[(v1 %in% c(0,3)) + 2*(v1 %in% c(1,5))]
```

Answer (score 6):

In the package **car** is the function `recode()`:

```
library("car")
v1 = c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)
# v2 = c(-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1)
recode(v1, "c(0, 3)=-1; else=1")
# [1] -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
```

or (if you want to set `NA` for values not in `c(0, 1, 3, 5)`):

```
recode(v1, "c(0, 3)=-1; c(1, 5)=1; else=NA")
```

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you are completely new to R. To do this you can simply create a vector `v2` which is all `0`s and use simple logical operators to the rest. As such:

```
v1 <- c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)
#this creates a vector in which 0 is repeated length(v1) times
v2 <- rep(0,length(v1)) 

v2[v1 == 1 | v2 == 5] <- 1
v2[v1 == 0 | v2 == 3] <- -1
```

Comment: why do you create a vector full of zeros instead of just define it as `v2 <- v1`?

Comment: @Seymour old numpy habits

Answer (score 3):

Your expected output is missing one value because its length is less than input vector length

```
v1 = c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)

v2 <- ifelse(v1 == 0 | v1 == 3, -1, ifelse(v1 == 1 | v1 == 5, 1, v1))

your_result <- c(-1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1)
identical(v2, your_result)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 v1 = c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)
 v2 <- ifelse(v1 == 0 | v1 == 3, -1, 1)
 v2
 # [1] -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
```

Alternative I to fill in an empty vector (using `vector()` function) condition wise (`ifelse()` function)

```
v1 = c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)
v1
# [1] 0 3 5 1 1 3 5 0

## Empty Numeric vector of length v1  
Vec <- vector("numeric",length = length(v1))
Vec
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

## Filling for 0 or 3
Vec[] <- ifelse(v1 == 0 | v1 == 3, -1, v1)
Vec
# [1] -1 -1  5  1  1 -1  5 -1

## Filling for 1 or 5
Vec[] <- ifelse(v1 == 1 | v1 == 5, 1, Vec)
Vec
# [1] -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
```

Alternative II using `%in%` alongwith `vector()` & `ifelse()` to fill in empty vector

```
v1 = c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)
v1
# [1] 0 3 5 1 1 3 5 0

Result <- vector("numeric",length = length(v1))
Result
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Result[] <- ifelse(v1 %in% c(0,3), -1, v1)
Result
# [1] -1 -1  5  1  1 -1  5 -1

Result[] <- ifelse(Result %in% c(1,5), 1, Result)
Result
# [1] -1 -1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
```

Comment: this solution does not take into account the second condition

Comment: Since there are only two conditions, you won't need it. Even though alternative has also been given by filling in an empty vector condition wise.

Answer (score 3):

you can also try a tidyverse solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
mutate(tibble(a=c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)),
              b=case_when(a %in% c(0,3) ~ -1,
                          a %in% c(1,5) ~ 1))
# A tibble: 9 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    0.   -1.
2    3.   -1.
3    5.    1.
4    1.    1.
5    1.    1.
6    1.    1.
7    3.   -1.
8    5.    1.
9    0.   -1.
```

adding `pull` gives you the vector

```
.Last.value %>% pull(b)
[1] -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
```

Answer (score 2):

I see lots of good answers, i will add one more programming like approach.

```
v1 <- c(0, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 0)
v2 <- integer(length(v1))

for (i in 1:length(v1)){
  # if val is equal to 0 or 3 new value is set to -1
  if (v1[i] == 0 | v1[i] == 3){
    new_val <- -1
  }
  # if val is equal to 1 or 5 new value is set to 1
  else if (v1[i] == 1 | v1[i] == 5 ){
    new_val <- 1
  }
  # else the value remains the same
  else{
    new_val <- v1[i]
  }
  v2[i] <- new_val 
}
v2
# -1 -1  1  1  1  1 -1  1 -1
```

Comment: This is less "programming like" because any good programmer knows that you don't grow a vector in a loop.

Comment: I guess my python nature took the best of me here. I understand that the vector is being copied all the time and that is might be slow for larger datasets. However, this is a small example and works fine. With more programming like i meant that it is more completely written out. Therefore, the one with the question could gain extra knowledge about R's possibilities. So i hope in the future you can keep the toxic comment to yourself. The stackoverflow community is already toxic enough.

Comment: A `for` loop is not what you should use in R for this, although it would be the tool of choice in more low-level programming languages. Thus, I assume you are showing this for didactic purposes only. However, if that is indeed the case, you of course should demonstrate good programming practices by preallocating the vector and assigning into it, which is easy to do in R and what you would do in other (more low-level) programming languages too. There is no excuse for promoting bad practice.

Comment: Changed the answer to a more efficient R solution. I go in to hiding now. Hopefully Roland won't find me :s